# what's the part before the dot in the name of the table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database in Microsoft SQL Server where the table names look like **firstpart.secondpart**. For example, Accounts.BankTransactionBASE or CustomerService.SurveyCommentBASE. I don't think the entire name is the name of the table, because when I find the name of the tables in the database using sys.tables, it only gives the second part of the name which is SurveyCommentBASE. Please see the image below.

[image]

I have two questions

1. What is this first part of the name?
2. How do I (change the 'select * from sys.tables' sql command) to get
   the first part of the name along with the second name, so I can
   perform my queries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naming format in SQL Server is: `servername.databasename.schemaname.tablename`. Typically only the last two are needed; the database name and server name are generally omitted as unnecessary unless you're working across multiple databases and/or servers.

In your case, the firstpart is the schema name and the secondpart is the table name. It's considered to be a good practice to use both schema and table name together to refer to tables, views, etc. in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers here have already said, the part before the table name is the schema. A simple edit to your query will get it for you:

```
select schema_name(schema_id), * from sys.tables
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question, you can get the schema and table name of all User tables from the `SYS` schema with:

```
SELECT s.name + '.' + t.name
FROM sys.schemas s JOIN sys.tables t ON t.schema_id=s.schema_id
WHERE t.type='U'
```